# Spring MVC Default View Resolver Not Working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I would like any requests that do not resolve to specific controller mappings to go to a view with a name derived from the request path.

Eg `localhost/success` should end up rendering a view located at `/WEB-INF/view/freemarker/success.ftl`. I gather from the [Spring documentation that this behaviour should be enabled by default](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-coc-r2vnt), by it doesn't appear to be working with my setup.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- On pre-handle, resolve the device that originated the web request -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Spring Mobile -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver">
    <constructor-arg>
        <!-- Freemarker -->
        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
            <property name="cache" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="mobilePrefix" value="mobile/" />
    <property name="tabletPrefix" value="tablet/" />
</bean>

<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/view/freemarker/" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was no `HandlerMapping` implementation found for these requests, and so `DispatcherServlet` never called the `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator`.

Adding the following provided the appropriate `HandlerMapping`, and thus filled in the missing link. The only downside now is that it's throwing exceptions logging at SEVERE for any requests that can't be satisfied, as opposed to `DispatcherServlet`'s more polite WARNING.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/*" />
```